# how to edit and publish my files at same time in mac os?

Tags: macos, unix, apache, chown

I have a serious problem. Every time I edit my source code, I have to do a `chown username:groupname` for my htdocs folder. Now if I have to publish my files and have them executed on the webserver, I have to do a `chown www:www` for things to work right.  I have tried to change my username,groupname in httpd.conf to my login in Mac OS but ownership still gets set incorrectly. I just want to be able to edit my source code and then not have to worry about changing the permissions.

What do I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably the easiest is to set the sticky bit of the enclosing directory and make `www` the group of it. So for example if you want to edit files in `/Library/WebServer/Documents` you would prepare it with

```
sudo chgrp www /Library/WebServer/Documents
sudo chmod g+s /Library/WebServer/Documents
```

Then all files you edit (or technically create) in `Documents` will have `www` group as well, so as long as your `umask` is reasonable (e.g. `0022`) they will be readable by the web server and you can edit them as you please.